# Autofill foreignkey in Django Admin Inline

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have `Employee` shown inline with `Company`. `Employee` belongs to a `Company` and a company specific `Department`.

I have to autofill the current company to the new Department form.

**# models.py**

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Department(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    company = models.ForeignKey("Company", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Employee(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey("User", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    company = models.ForeignKey("Company", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    department = models.ForeignKey("Department", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**# admin.py**

```
@admin.register(Company)
class CompanyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        EmployeeInCompany_Inline,
    ]

class EmployeeInCompany_Inline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Employee
```

**Edit Company Page**
[image]

**New Department Popup**
[image]

Comment: Do you need the employee -> company foreign key? If an employee is assigned to a department then the company is already defined. `Employee.department.company`

Comment: You are correct Iain. I chose `Company` -> `Employee` since it is more direct and can be easily inlined in Django Admin. `Company` -> `Department` -> `Employee` although more normalised, has more levels and has to be nested inlined. Also, in our usecase, smaller companies dont have departments.

Comment: You can provide initial data to any admin form by passing a query parameter. If you add "&company=<company_id>" to the department popup URL you should get the field pre-populated. How you would add this to the button I'm not sure